# Django Group Permissions in React

Tags: django, reactjs

In Django I have added a group and can see it on my template by using:

```
{{ perms.mygroup }}
```

I have a React front end app which has a number of links to navigate around the front end but the 'Edit' link must only be visible if the user has the 'mygroup' permission stated above.

How is it that I pass the server permission to the front end app?
Am I missing something simple here as I can't find out how to do it.
I've read about using React's new context API but the examples I've seen are setting the context on the front end, rather than bringing in a variable from the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a RESTful API service for this is the most optimal solution. But you can use the context data in react application through window object like this:

In template, add the following code:

```
<script>
window.hasPerm = "{{ perms.mygroup }}"
</script>
```

And in react application:

```
{ window.hasPerm && <button onClick=...>
```

Comment: That worked well, thank you!  I'd like to know more about the RESTful API, I currently have one working for another part of the application which retrieves database objects but never considered it for permissions.

Comment: You can use Django Rest Framework to generate an API to fetch permission data from Django. Then consume this API in react or write a middleware in redux to use these data. But that is a long implementation.